# Efficient Hessian-Laplace blob detector implementation

Tags: image-processing, scipy, computer-vision

As it is mentioned in a paper for [SURF](ftp://ftp.vision.ee.ethz.ch/publications/articles/eth_biwi_00517.pdf), it is possible to approximate hessian determinant using integral images.

If I want to implement Hessian-Laplace detector, is it feasible to also approximate Laplacian of Gaussian with the same approach?

Basically, I want to use the fast determinant of Hessian from SURF and while computing it, also get the laplacian by taking the trace of Hessian.

Comment: You'll get better (in this case: more) replies, if you also show your first attempt at implementing the proposed algorithm. Not everyone is willing to read through a paper, trying to understand the algorithm just for a few points of virtual reputation.

Comment: Hi Would you support Image Processing group to answer such questions? See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision. Just up vote questions with less than 10 votes.

Answer (score 0):

"is it feasible to also approximate Laplacian of Gaussian with the same approach?" In 2008 Agrawal et al. published this:
- http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-88693-8_8

It's a blob detector that approximates the laplacian of gaussian with integral and rotated integral images. Hope this helps.